# Python How to display a counter while the user is typing

Tags: python, user-interface, user-input, python-3.4

I'm making a Twitter API and I'm wondering how can I show to the user the lenght of the text while he is typing? Twitter has 140 limit in tweets, so I want to show user the lenght of the text. I'll use it with PyQt5 actually, but I don't know how can I show it while user is typing. Even if I know how can I do it with `input()` I guess I can convert it to PyQt5.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Look into a KeyPressEvent for your input field

Comment: FWIW, it's  _much_ easier to do that in a GUI than in the terminal. As cricket said, there should be some way to call a callback function on each keypress in an Entry widget. That sort of thing is commonly used for validating input, and in this case you're wanting to validate the input's length; you could also use it perform spell-checking.

Comment: For the record, you really *can't* just take something designed to use `input()` and bolt a GUI on, except for very simple things.  The basic assumption that `input()` will block the rest of your program, for example, is not generally applicable to GUIs.